# How to block all wireless non-bluetooth devices using udev

Tags: udev, devices, bluetooth, block-device

How to block all wireless non-bluetooth devices in udev
(that require an USB adapter to attach to computer)
?
I want to block permanently all wireless HID devices such as wireless mice or keyboard .

Comment: can you expand the question a little more, explain what you want

Comment: Those wireless hid receivers might not even need to expose to the system in any way that they operates with wireless mice and keyboards. Though I suppose you can blacklist vendor-specific drivers that are known to be (e.g. `hid-logitech-*`) for one of those with a modprobe conf (or build a kernel without those drivers).